# Check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of a collection (first argument)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

you are given an array collection of objects. The predicate pre will be an object property and you need to return true if its value is truthy. Otherwise, return false.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
 //To Do
}

truthCheck(
   [
     { user: "Tinky-Winky", sex: "male" },
     { user: "Dipsy", sex: "male" },
     { user: "Laa-Laa", sex: "female" },
     { user: "Po", sex: "female" }
   ],
   "sex"
);
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: `"sex"` is not a predicate. It's a string. Do you mean property name?

Comment: In JS we call them "arrays", not "collections".

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for it and check every element with the given key for truthyness.

> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function truthCheck(array, key) {
    return array.every(function (a) {
        return a[key];
    });
}

console.log(truthCheck([{ "user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male" }, { "user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male" }, { "user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female" }, { "user": "Po", "sex": "female" }], "sex"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so here it goes as an answer. His question comes from a [freeCodeCamp bonfire](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/everything-be-true):

Create an algorithm to check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of a collection (first argument). He must create a `function truthCheck(collection, pre)` that, with the arguments

```
collection = [{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}];
```

and

```
pre = "sex";
```

should return true.

Basically, you must take the second argument (ie 'sex') and see if it has a *truthy* value on all objects on array collection. Keep in mind [that truthy means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) anything different than false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN. With that explanation, you should be able to complete your exercise. But next time I'd suggest you click the "Get a hint" button within freeCodeCamp before asking it here.

And there is detailed discussion and well explained answers with proper reasoning at [FreeCodeCamp discussion forum](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/freecodecamp-algorithm-challenge-guide-everything-be-true/16011/2)